# How to fiz this warning: warning #1011: missing return statement at end of non-void function "G"?

Tags: c++, c, warnings

I'm using a function called G to describe a EDO for a runge-kutta method and i keep getting this warning: warning #1011: missing return statement at end of non-void function "G". The code works perfectly, but I prefer not to have any kind of warnings. How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Here is the function:

```
double G(double t, double x[], int j)
{
    if (j == 0) return (x[1]);
    if (j == 1) return (gama * sin(OMEGA*t) - zeta * x[1] - alpha * x[0] - beta * pow(x[0], 3) - chi * x[2]);
    if (j == 2) return (-kappa * x[1] - phi * x[2]);
}
```

Comment: What happens if `j` equals `3` or more, or less that `0` ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what case of error handling you want, but the easiest way is to somehow print a diagnostic message (`printf?`) and return `NAN`.

A switch statement will also help the compiler tell you more explicitely that you missed a case:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int gama, zeta, alpha, beta, chi, kappa, OMEGA, phi;
double G(double t, double x[], int j)
{
    switch(j) {
        case 0: return (x[1]);
        case 1: return (gama * sin(OMEGA*t) - zeta * x[1] - alpha * x[0] - beta * pow(x[0], 3) - chi * x[2]);
        case 2: return (-kappa * x[1] - phi * x[2]);
        default:
#ifdef __cplusplus
            throw std::invalid_argument("…");
#else
            printf("Invalid j %d in %s", j, __func__);
#endif
            return NAN;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 returning NAN is the right solution here. returning -1 or any other number or std::optional is not good or overkill. One could argue about the `printf`, though.

Comment: @AndreasH. Sure, there are better ways but there's nothing about his environment in the question.

Comment: @AndreasH. Returning NAN is not the correct solution. In reality, the correct solution here is to throw an exception, as inputting j = 5 is a logical error. Exceptions are free until they are called, so it is extremely lightweight.

Comment: The question is also tagged as C which doesn't have exceptions. Edit: added throwing an exception if compiling as c++

Comment: @tstenner That is an error on your part, it should be tagged with c++ or c, not both.

Comment: @AlexHodges NAN usually means "undefined", so I think is appropriate to return NAN even in case of a logical error. The nice thing about NAN is that it is exception free so can be used when there are no exceptions (-> C) or exceptions are disallowed. Advantages of exceptions are that one could find out where it originates from, which is more difficult for NAN. So, yes, in case one has exceptions (and can/wants to use them) it is better than using a (quiet) NAN.

Comment: @tstenner In the context of this question looking for an answer in C, you make a very reasonable argument and i'm inclined to agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

These are all conditional returns.
What if, non of these condition matches...Hence is the warning.
Kindly have a default return value at the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have not considered all cases. There can be situations where the three if statements fail.

In such cases you need to return some error which will not occur normally. e.g. you return `-1` The exact value to return will depend on the calling function and how you handle the error case.

```
double G(double t, double x[], int j)
{
    if (j == 0) return (x[1]);
    if (j == 1) return (gama * sin(OMEGA*t) - zeta * x[1] - alpha * x[0] - beta * pow(x[0], 3) - chi * x[2]);
    if (j == 2) return (-kappa * x[1] - phi * x[2]);

    return (-1);
}
```

Comment: i wrote in a way that j  == 3 + never happens, this way the code works perfectly but keep showing the warning (but, of course the compiler doesnt know it...). So, this way (return (-1)), should it stop showing the warning and the code working as before? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not written return statements for all possible paths in your function.

Here are two possible ways you could implement this functionality:

std::optional

```
std::optional<double> G(double t, double x[], int j)
{
    auto result = std::optional<double>();
    if (j == 0) result = x[1];
    if (j == 1) result = (gama * sin(OMEGA*t) - zeta * x[1] - alpha * x[0] - beta * pow(x[0], 3) - chi * x[2]);
    if (j == 2) result = (-kappa * x[1] - phi * x[2]);

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto result = G(.....)
    if (result.has_value())
    {
        // Correct arguments
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        // Incorrect
        //...
    }
}
```

std::exception

```
double G(double t, double x[], int j)
{
    double result;
    if (j == 0) result = x[1];
    else if (j == 1) result = (gama * sin(OMEGA*t) - zeta * x[1] - alpha * x[0] - beta * pow(x[0], 3) - chi * x[2]);
    else if (j == 2) result = (-kappa * x[1] - phi * x[2]);
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Unable to find a valid code path");   
    }

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try{
        auto result = G(.....)
    }
    catch (std::invalid_argument & ec){
        // Handle error
    };
}
```